# Lynda offline videos windows app

Tags: video, download, windows-store-apps, windows

I am referring to the below questions with lynda windows app
[How to find and play videos downloaded by Lynda.com Android or Windows app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621963/how-to-find-and-play-videos-downloaded-by-lynda-com-android-or-windows-app)

This was working some where like 3 months back. and now I am getting files with .LDCW extension

which is not readable by any player ( tested vlc and windows media player)

Any suggestions to decode or play these ?

Answer (score 1):

Now offline App Encrypt files so it can only decrypted and played with lynda offline App only

if any one needs how to decrypt files I have already developed tool for my personnel use to do so but I think I can not share it for public

Comment: may be you could share us some procedure or algorithm to decrypt them. May be I could decrypt them myself if you could share some info

Answer (score 0):

So I just tested it and the .LDCW extension does play in VLC media player. I used the desktop version (not the Windows store version).

Make sure you have the most updated VLC.

**Edit: And it just stopped working.. let me see if I can figure out again how I got it playing**